# R - convert each row of a matrix in a character vector and save as named list

Tags: r, list, matrix, bioconductor

I have a matrix containing biological pathways (rows) and corresponding genes (columns). If a gene is present in a pathway the cell contains 1, otherwise 0. See example below:

`mat=matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)`

`row.names(mat) = c("pathwayX", "pathwayY", "pathwayZ")`

`colnames(mat) = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3")`

|  | Gene1 | Gene2 | Gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pathwayX | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| pathwayY | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| pathwayZ | 1 | 1 | 1 |

What I need is a character vector for each pathway with constituting genes, holded in a list (e. g named gene_sets). In this example this would be:

```
> gene_sets
$pathwayX
"Gene3"

$pathwayY
"Gene2" "Gene3"

$pathwayZ
"Gene1" "Gene2" "Gene3"
```

Additionally, I need character vectors describing the pathway name, holded in a list (e. g. named description). In this example this would be:

```
> description
$pathwayX
"pathwayX"

$pathwayY
"pathwayY"

$pathwayZ
"pathwayZ"
```

Background: The vector lists are needed for the package pathfindR with costum input
(https://github.com/egeulgen/pathfindR/wiki/Analysis-Using-Custom-Gene-Sets).

Comment: Try `apply(mat, 1, \(x) colnames(mat)[x]); setNames(as.list(rownames(mat)), rownames(mat))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done giving us a reproducible example. You can use the `apply` family of functions where `lapply` gives you a list as output, `sapply` will try to simplify the result, and `apply` lets you decide if you want to apply the function over rows or columns of a `data.frame` using the `margin` argument.
(default is columns if used with `lapply` or `sapply`).

```
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
gene_sets <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) colnames(mat)[x==1])
description <- lapply(row.names(mat), function(x) x)
names(description) <- row.names(mat)
> gene_sets
$pathwayX
[1] "Gene3"

$pathwayY
[1] "Gene2" "Gene3"

$pathwayZ
[1] "Gene1" "Gene2" "Gene3"

> description
$pathwayX
[1] "pathwayX"

$pathwayY
[1] "pathwayY"

$pathwayZ
[1] "pathwayZ"
```

Not sure I follow your logic regarding the `description` list, but this seems to give your expected result.

Comment: perfect, that worked!
Thansk a lot :-)

Comment: if the answer is satisfactory, please mark is as accepted.